# mercurial phases, warning when changing phase to secret

Tags: mercurial

Whenever I change a phase from draft to secret, I get a warning. I don't see a danger, am I missing something?

Also is there a way to turn off the warning, and not have to add `--force`? If I am always overriding the “safety” then one day I will accidentally change phase from public. As far as I can see public is the only phase that should never be changed. (If we should only move phases forward, and start on the second phase/step, then the first phase/step is useless).

So the questions are:

- Am I missing something in my understanding, is moving from draft to secret ever dangerous? Why should I be worried? what should I be looking out for? what could go wrong?
- How do I allow change to secret, if current phase is draft, without a warning or use of `--force`? May be some sort of alias, preferably also works in tortoise.

Answer (score 0):

### Secret phase changesets are, well, "secret" and this changeset with descendants will not be pushed|pulled on sync

> is there a way to turn off the warning, and not have to add --force?

From `hg help phase`

> Unless -f/--force is specified, "hg phase" won't move changeset from a lower phase to an higher phase. Phases are ordered as follows:
>
> ```
>  public < draft < secret
> ```

-

> If we should only move phases forward, and start on the second phase/step, then the first phase/step is useless

You can change phase by hand (`-s -f`), when (if) it needed

> How do I allow change to secret, if current phase is draft, without a warning or use of --force?

Nohow. You **must** use `--force` (directly or in alias)

Comment: This is a repetition of the facts in the question (in more detail). However there is no answer here, except to confirm what I said. Do you find it odd that you are discouraged to change from draft to secret? Why should I be worried? what should I be looking out for? what could go wrong?

Comment: @richard - I repeat you **documents**, where are all answers on all your questions. "Do you find it odd...?" No. I'm not discouraged, just have one additional check-mark in process "Why should I be worried?" Because rule of 95% is true, and if today `-f` will be eliminated, tomorrow SO will be flooded by "I can't push my changeset. FIX IT! My boss want to kill me, and *your tool doesn't work!!!* " "Why should I be worried?" - because `secret` phase have some side-effects "what should I be looking out for?" os it really needed? Was I warned about all consequences? Am I sure?